# Android: List position from AutoCompleteTextview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

How can I get the position of an item from a List that I selected from an AutoCompleteTextview?

```
autoSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoSearch);
    autoSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

        }
    });
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mLIST);
    autoSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Using the variable arg2 only gets me the position of the AutoComplete list and not the actual position of the item that is on my mLIST.

Is there a way to get the actual position and not the AutoComplete position?

Comment: can you post how looks your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quick solution, imho very lazy but it works. I was assuming you have unique words, haven't you? Otherwise you would need make customadapter and use setTag() for items.

```
autoSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                Log.d("xxx", "xxx");

                String text = ((TextView) arg1).getText().toString();
                for(int i=0;i<mLIST.size();i++)
                {
                    if(mLIST.get(i).contains(text))
                    {
                        int lookingForId = i;
                        Log.d("xxx", "looking for id is " + i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Was thinking of going this route but I was hoping there is a more direct approach. Also some of the items in my list have the same content. But I can use this. I just have to change my approach to my app. THanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure there's a direct way, but knowing the selected item from the list you can know its position in your `mLIST` using `indexOf()` method on your list.

That assuming each item is unique, if not, this will not work.